# Is it better to declare variables inside or outside the prototype property?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, instance-variables

Which of the following cases is better for performance or proper techniques?

**CASE #1**

```
function SomeClass ()
{
    this.someVar = null;
    this.someFunc = function () {}
}
```

**CASE #2**

```
function SomeClass () {}
SomeClass.prototype.someVar = null;
SomeClass.prototype.someFunc = function () {}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on whether you want them shared between instances created via that constructor function. If you do, put them on the prototype. If you don't, set them up in the constructor.

Beware that putting references to objects/arrays on the prototype is likely to trip you up, as (again) all instances will share those references.

Putting methods (references to functions) on the prototype is fairly standard practice.

---

Here's an example of getting tripped up by putting an array on the prototype:

```js
function MyConstructor() {
};
MyConstructor.prototype.theArray = []; // Don't do this unless you're really sure

var a = new MyConstructor();
a.theArray.push("foo");
snippet.log(a.theArray.length); // 1 -- so far, everything seems fine

var b = new MyConstructor();
b.theArray.push("bar");
snippet.log(b.theArray.length); // 2 -- huh?!?!
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

The reason, of course, is that both `a` and `b` are using the **same** array: The one on the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

if they are shared among all of the instances of `SomeClass`, It's better to declare it in the prototype because they will share the same reference which reduces the amount of memory.

but if these properties varies from instance to another, you must declare it in the constructor.

**Examples:**

```
function SomeClass () {}
SomeClass.prototype.someVar = null;
SomeClass.prototype.someFunc = function () {}

var a = new SomeClass();
var b = new SomeClass();
a.someFunc === b.someFunc //true because they share the same reference
```

within constructor:

```
function SomeClass ()
{
    this.someVar = null;
    this.someFunc = function () {}
}

var a = new SomeClass();
var b = new SomeClass();
a.someFunc === b.someFunc //false because the now have difference reference
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one will be faster

```
function SomeClass ()
{
    this.someVar = null;
    this.someFunc = function () {}
}
```

because in this case while accessing `someClassInstace.someFunc` javascript will not look up in prototype for someFunc function.

Comment: However in another article I read that putting function inside SomeClass would make it slower because it needs to create it. (source:http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/: "In the first version, each time you create a person, a new sayHi function will be created for him, where as in the second version, only one sayHi function is ever created, and is shared amongst all persons that are created - because Person.prototype is their parent. Thus, declaring methods on the prototype is more memory efficient.") Not sure if this is true tho.

Comment: @Mark creation object can be slow, but while accessing the function in instance it should be fast, but i don't think it would make that much of performance difference

Comment: *"I think the first one will be faster"* The difference would be ***infinitesimal*** even if modern JavaScript engines weren't optimizing compilers (which they are, rendering even that infinitesimal moot).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right